# how to handle multiple requests in a flask code

Tags: python, multithreading, flask, parallel-processing

I have a flask code which fetches the details from users in multiple forms (the forms are dependent on each other) and based on the details the user has entered the python backend script will be called and performs operation and the result will be displayed on ui, but when multiple users are submitting the form details at same time then it is taking first user's inputs to process and displaying the first user's result to all users who are accessing. how to resolve this?

Comment: By fixing your code to not share state. You aren't showing us what you're doing, so it's impossible to help.